# Spring Boot application to read data from FTP server and store in Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-blob-storage

How to read data for example files ( blob ) from FTP via Spring Boot Rest API and upload into Azure Blob storage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to my code, this solution saves the ftp file as a local temporary file and then uploads it to Azure storage, maybe you need to delete it after uploading.

```
        // Create a BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectStr).buildClient();
        // Create the container and return a container client object
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        // Get a reference to a blob
        BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(fileName);

        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        try {
            ftpClient.connect(server);
            ftpClient.login(username, password);

            File file = new File(ftpFileName);
            if(file.exists()) {
                file.delete();
            }
            ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(directory);
            ftpClient.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            OutputStream outputStream = null;
            boolean success = false;
            outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(ftpFileName));
            success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(ftpFileName, outputStream);

            blobClient.uploadFromFile(ftpFileName);
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            ...
        }
```